# How can I find the type of a datasource?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-binding, immediate-window

I am trying to debug the following line of code

```
binding.DataSource = this.bindingSource.DataSource;
```

and want to find out more information about binding.DataSource

In the immediate window the query ? binding.DataSource  returns

```
Count = 1
[0]: {Contact Events}
```

I want to cast the binding.DataSource to something I can query with intellisense?
What should  I cast it to ?

[Update] 
The binding source was created as follows;

```
public BindingSource GetEventTypesBindingSource()
    {
        try
        {
          DbSet<ContactEventType> dset = base.Context.ContactEventTypes;
          IOrderedQueryable<ContactEventType> qry = dset.Where(p => p.Id > 0).OrderBy(x => x.Description);
            qry.Load();
            var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
            bindingSource.DataSource = dset.Local.ToBindingList();
            return bindingSource;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException.Show(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

[Update]
I tried the following in the debugger

```
? (List<ContactEvent>) binding.DataSource.GetType()
```

but get

```
The type or namespace name 'List' is not valid in this scope
```

Comment: `DataSource` of all the Data Binding controls is of type `object`. Didn't get your question by "what I can cast to it". Already on the form load or somewhere, a DataSource should have been assigned to the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably `List<ContactEvent>`, but you can find out using the debugger and/or reflection.

If you view the variable in the Watch window of the debugger, it will show the type of the data.  If you call GetType on the datasource it will return the type of the object (you can do this in the debugger too, and examine the resulting type there).

Comment: How do I find out using the debugger and/or reflection?

Answer (score 1):

first its not related to answer but you dont have to use datasource in this case (you dont use datamember property). you can just bind it to the collection directly.
the type of collection could be a custom bindinglist implementation from entity framework assembly. maybe you dont see its name because its not public, but casting to IEnumerable should work.
if i remember correctly that custom implementation derive from BindingList so BindingList is also ok.